# Loading Data from SQL into Tabulator

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, tabulator

I want to load data from my SQL Table into Tabulator but I'm always receiving the AJAX Error: `"parsererror"`, which is created by my ajax code: `"console.log('my message: ' + err)"`.

Can somebody please help where this error is coming from and how to solve it?

You can find my used code below.

My table is defines as following:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {

    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    columns:[
        {title:"Date", field:"Date", align:"center", sorter:"date", widthGrow:2},
        {title:"Country", field:"Country"},
        {title:"Onlineshop", field:"Onlineshop"},
        {title:"Preis in € excl. MwSt.", field:"Onlineprice_euro", align:"right", sorter:"number"},
        {title:"Onlineshop_URL", field:"Shop_url", widthGrow:2},

    ], 
});
```

I'm loading the data by using the following ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch_onlinepricetable.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{ean:ean},
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data)
    {                          
        table.setData(data);                           
    },
    error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message: ' + err);}
});
```

My PHP function for loading the data is the following:

```
<?php

    $servername = "####";
    $username = "####";
    $password = "####";
    $dbname = "####";

    $con=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $sql = "SELECT Country,Onlineshop,Shop_url,Date,Onlineprice_euro FROM onlineprices WHERE EAN = '" . $_POST["ean"]. "'";

    $result = $query_id = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    foreach($result as $row)
    {

        $data[] = array(
            'Date' => $row["Date"],
            'Country' => $row["Country"],
            'Onlineshop' => $row["Onlineshop"],
            'Onlineprice_euro' => $row["Onlineprice_euro"],
            'Shop_url' => $row["Shop_url"]
        );

    };

    echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you show the response of your ajax request in network tab?

Comment: I hope this is what you mean: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh8twbior3qmaje/Screenshot%20network%20tab.JPG?dl=0). (I uploaded the image to my dropbox)

Comment: Yes.. but the picture shows header only... I need response text.... Go to `antwort` tab

Comment: Please find the response text in the attached image. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/93dz7nwbguboflt/Screenshot%20response.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: You can also find attached an example sql query executed in phpmyadmin [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d435x4uk1c7ef6h/Example%20sql%20query.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you this already helped to get a response [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd7q12g06qtoin7/result%201.JPG?dl=0). But not I'm receiving following error at my console [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81xu5nvw0lho0nt/error.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Fine,,,, You are receiving object instead of array... To convert it as array of object, In you php change the line `echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` to `echo "[".json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."]";`

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot in your comment section.
[Response](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd7q12g06qtoin7/result%201.JPG?dl=0)
[Console Error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81xu5nvw0lho0nt/error.JPG?dl=0)

You are receiving object instead of array... To convert it as array of object,

In you php change the line

`echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

to

`echo "[".json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."]";`